# Django-south team workflow with single dev DB

Tags: django, django-south

I'm interested in how to use south in some specific team workflow. Our team have single DB for all dev enviroments.
So, for example: one developer starting to code some feature in new branch, and this features needs some db migrations. They does initial/subsequent migrations with South as needed. At this point, there is specific rows in DB in south_migrationhistory table. Suppose it looks like

```
10    app1_name    0001_initial           <timestamp>
11    app1_name    0002_needed_changes    <timestamp>
```

At this point, this new feature branch isnt merged anywhere and not even pushed to origin repo, so noone but single developer knows about such changes in code.

At the same time, there's another developer who implementing some other feature (even for other django app) that needs migrations too. When this dev tries to make migrations needed, they'll face issue with South, 'cause there's existing db rows with initial migrations (made by first developer) but there's no actual migrations in VCS yet. Such situation produces

```
$ manage.py convert_to_south app2
....
south.exceptions.NoMigrations: Application '<module 'apps.app1' from '/home/user/dev/apps/app1/__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.
```

Is there any solution for such workflow or it just need to be changed?